# update all the matching elements of array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

my array is as following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5704cf4da64ffd34d7285fef"),
    "names" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "harjeet"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "harjeet123"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "harjeet1234"
        }
    ]
}
```

i need to update name as "harjeet12345", all of them.

my research found about this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243

Is there any way to perform this update

Comment: do u want to set to "harjeet12345" every "name" array element of "names" field of every document in the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var nameStr = "harjeet12345";
c.find().forEach(function (doc) {
    var newNameArray = [];
    doc.names.forEach(function (y) {
        var newName = {name : "zeugor"}
        newNameArray.push(newName);
    });

    c.update(
        { _id: doc._id},
        {"$set" : {"names" : newNameArray}}
    )    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as you know this is an issue with mongodb embedded documents and array of documents. Since mongodb [MongoDB jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243) have approved its modification but that is still pending and hope to see in next release.
here is something you can use for now

```
db.yourcollection.find({}).forEach(function(tmp){
    names = [];
    tmp.names.forEach(function(name){
        names.push({name : 'rummykhan'})
    });
    tmp.names = names;
    db.yourcollection.save(tmp)
})
```